# Where to store public key for ssh on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, git, node.js, ubuntu, ssh

I have a nodejs application under git control version and a git account for managing this one?

```
sudo adduser \
  --system \
  --shell /bin/bash \
  --gecos ‘User managing of git version control’ \
  --group \
  --disabled-password \
  --home /home/git \
  git
```

Where should I store authorized_keys file

```
/home/git/authorized_keys
```

Or

```
/home/user/authorized_keys
```

Where user is normal user on my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys

check this link: http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-4.html

Comment: Thanks. But I can't su login under git user. When I do su git I get 'Password: '. But I've provide --disabled-password. What's problem?

Comment: Use 'su', enter your root password. After logging in as root, enter 'su git'

You will now be logged in as 'git' user.

Comment: What in case of multiple servers?

Answer (score 1):

The directory should be at:

```
/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
```